# Typescript :Types of property 'value' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React Context on a TypeScript project and have run into the following error.

```
Argument of type 'Context<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context<IsProductContext>'.
  The types of 'Provider.propTypes' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'WeakValidationMap<ProviderProps<{}>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<ProviderProps<IsProductContext>> | undefined'.
      Type 'WeakValidationMap<ProviderProps<{}>>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<ProviderProps<IsProductContext>>'.
        Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
          Type 'Validator<{}> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Validator<IsProductContext> | undefined'.
            Type 'Validator<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<IsProductContext>'.
              Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IsProductContext'.
```

`products` data is being displayed in console so it's passing down to the component, but i've not come across this `ts` error before. If anyone can explain what the actual issue is it would be appreciated.

```
export const ProductContext = createContext({});
```

App.tsx

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState<IsProduct>({
        list: [
            {
                name: 'Test One',
                price: 1,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                name: 'Test Two',
                price: 1,
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
    });

    <ProductContext.Provider value={{ products, setProducts }}>
            <SomeComponent />
        </ProductContext.Provider>
```

SomeComponent

```
const { products, setProducts } = useContext<IsProductContext>(ProductContext);
```

Interfaces

```
export interface IsProduct {
    list:
        | {
              name: string;
              price: number;
              quantity: number | null;
          }[]
        | undefined;
}

export interface IsProductContext {
    products: IsProduct;
    setProducts: (products: IsProduct) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by using `const { products, setProducts } = useContext(ProductContext) as IsProductContext;` instead of `const { products, setProducts } = useContext<IsProductContext>(ProductContext);`